# Nest IF function returns false

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a nested IF function that is simple but it returns false if you input a number like 350, however for a number like 199: it works (it puts the correct corresponding number, in this case 7.5). Whenever I put in 350, it returns as false.

```
=IF(E13>500,"2.5",IF(E13<=500/350,"3.5",IF(E13<=350/200,"4.5",IF(E13<=200,"7.5"))))
```

I am not sure why it is broken.

Comment: It's not broken. 350 does not satisfy any of the specified conditions. Note that `500/350` and `350/200` are division. Did you mean to use something like `=IF(E13>500,"2.5",IF(E13>350,"3.5",IF(E13>200,"4.5","7.5")))`?

Comment: ^^^ and you have no false clause on the final If, so it returns the default  `FALSE`

Comment: yes that worked flawlessly thanks!